# Is it able to retrieve segment of an array value in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Assuming I have a document like this:

```
{
  'seq': [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9],
}
```

which is indexed in Elasticsearch by `index='a'`, `type='b'` and `id='c'`, and with `integer` mapping. I wonder is it possible to only get a segment of the `seq` array (for example, only get the `seq[2:5] = [2, 3, 5, 7]`) as the `_source` field of response. I'd like to do this because I may have thousands of values in the array `seq`, but I only need some of them every time. I think it is bad to retrieve all the values every time, and then get the segment that I need.

In my mind, I think the `aggregations` in Elasticsearch may be helpful, but I don't know exactly how to use it in this issue.

Any other approaches instead of using Elasticsearch is also welcomed. Hoping to hear your brilliant ideas.

Comment: That's not possible. But what is the use case? And why do you think this use-case can have a solution with aggregations?

Comment: Totally impossible? I need this array to determine the sequence of other data.   Isn't `aggregations` a method to process the documents retrieved by `get` or `search` API?

Comment: Yes, totally. How do you determine it's `seq[2:5]`? Where do `2` and `5` come from?

Comment: I can have this two values from other place of my programs. They can be settled in the first place. I just don't know how to get values of array from Elasticsearch only in that scope.